# Is a neural network able to learn to map a completely different feature vector to the same class

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, feature-engineering

Is a neural network (for example a MLPClassifier in Python) able to learn to map a completely (or very) different input feature set to the same output class? Or is it better to work in this case with more than one output class and map these recognized output classes afterwards to the same class manually?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are naming "completely different feature set"? Is it a zone of the input space that is not available in training data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, neural networks excel at finding highly non-linear decision boundaries. For example, take a look at this [demo](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.40455&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) (don't forget to click the play button to make the network learn). Even this very simple network is able to learn that the opposite corners of the input space belong to the same class.

Comment: Able yes. But is it better to train a own classifier for this featureset?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then yes, neural networks are exceptional in spotting patterns in data (even unstructured like images) and output the correct label

> Or is it better to work in this case with more than one output class and map these recognized output classes afterwards to the same class manually

I am not sure I understand what you mean by this but essentially the output layer of your neural network should have just as many neurons as you have possible outputs when it comes to classification (except for binary classification where only one neuron is enough).